# partition function of the U=0 Hubbard model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

I'm trying to derive the following partition function for the U=0 Hubbard model:

$Z=\prod_\mathbf{k}(1+e^{-\beta(\epsilon_\mathbf{k}-\mu)})$

My try was to use:

$Z=\sum_{\sigma,\mathbf{k}} <\sigma,\mathbf{k}|e^{-\beta H}|\sigma,\mathbf{k}>$

where $H=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}(\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\mu)c_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}$; and to expand the exponential. However I seem to get something like:

$Z=2\sum_{\mathbf{k}}e^{-\beta(\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\mu)}$

Comment: Note: I've seen proven already in a different context the known-fact that the partition function of a system composed by independent subsystems (in this case independent modes) is the product of the partition functions of the different subsystems. But I can't see how that comes into play here.

Comment: The Hamiltonian is $\mathbf{k}$-diagonal, hence the different quasi-momentum modes indexed by $\mathbf{k}$ are statistically independent. Each of these modes has two possible states (for fermions): 1) unoccupied with Boltzmann weight 1 (zero energy contribution) and 2) occupied with Boltzmann weight $e^{-\beta(\epsilon_\mathbf{k}-\mu)}$. (Your attempt seems to assume there is just a single particle which could be in different states $\mathbf{k}$. Actually $Z$ is a sum over all possible states with all possible numbers of particles in the many-body system.)

Comment: Alright, if I understood I'm mixing the one particle picture of a tight-binding hamiltonian where $H$ would describe the Hamiltonian of the electron in the lattice, with that of what this model seems to do, mainly describe the energies of many electrons (given that $\mu \neq 0$). What basis should I choose then to calculate $Z$ of the system?

Comment: As (almost) always in many-body physics, you want the occupation number representation. This labels the states by how many particles are in each mode, e.g. the state $\lvert n_1 n_2 n_3 \ldots \rangle$ means $n_k=0,1$ particles in mode $k$. All possible combinations of $n_k$ form a complete basis. Do the trace in this basis and use the fact that $e^{-\beta H}$ is a product over different modes $k$ (because $H$ is a sum), you should eventually get the expression you want. Or you could use the fact that the $k$ modes are independent from the start, and just write down the answer.

Comment: BTW this model contains the 1-particle tight-binding model that you mention, but it's more general because you can have any number of particles. Rather than summing over the possible states of 1 particle, then 2 particles, then 3 particles, etc., you just sum over the states of the independent modes (i.e. "occupied" or "unoccupied"), which comes out to be a lot simpler. But in the end either way would work (definitely do it the second way, though!).

Comment: I see. Anyway, I think the state should be chosen so as to take into account spin degeneracy per mode $\mathbf{k}$. So taking the state $|n>=|n_{1+} n_{1-} n_{2+} n_{2-} ...>$ where $n_{1+}$ denotes the occupation number for a particle with $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k_1}$ and spin up. With that I get though the result: $Z=\prod_{\mathbf{k}}(1+e^{-\beta (\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\mu)})^2$, which differs from the expected result.

Comment: Yes, which is the product of the partition functions for two independent spin species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write the Hamiltonian as
$$ H = \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \sum_{\sigma=1,2} \xi_\mathbf{k} \hat{n}_\mathbf{k,\sigma},$$
where $\xi_\mathbf{k} = \epsilon_\mathbf{k} - \mu$, and $\hat{n}_{\mathbf{k}\sigma} = c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma}$. Now let's compute the partition function
$$ Z = \mathrm{Tr} \left[\mathrm{e}^{-\beta H}\right] = \mathrm{Tr} \left[\bigotimes_{\mathbf{k},\sigma} \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k} \hat{n}_\mathbf{k\sigma}}\right] = \prod_\mathbf{k} \prod_{\sigma = 1,2} \mathrm{Tr}_\mathbf{k,\sigma}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k} \hat{n}_\mathbf{k\sigma}}\right].$$
The second equality follows because the Hamiltonian is a sum over independent modes, so its exponential is a tensor product. In the third equality I turned the trace of a tensor product into the product of partial traces $\mathrm{Tr}_\mathbf{k,\sigma}$ over the different Hilbert spaces of the independent modes. Now the problem is easy, because we know the eigenvalues of $\hat{n}_\mathbf{k\sigma}$ are $n_\mathbf{k\sigma} = 0,1$, so
$$ \mathrm{Tr}_\mathbf{k,\sigma}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k} \hat{n}_\mathbf{k\sigma}}\right] = \sum_{n_\mathbf{k\sigma} = 0,1}\mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k} n_\mathbf{k\sigma}} = 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k}}.$$
Putting it all together you get
$$ Z = \prod_\mathbf{k}\prod_{\sigma = 1,2}\left( 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k}}\right),$$
which is the usual way of writing the partition function. However, you can also note that the energies $\xi_\mathbf{k}$ are independent of the spin index $\sigma$, allowing you to write
$$ Z = \prod_\mathbf{k}\left( 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \xi_\mathbf{k}}\right)^2.$$
This must be the case since the free energy $\sim \log Z$ is additive for the two independent spin species.